# How can you tell if an application author or user is the one controlling or processing data?

Tags: privacy, data-protection, any-jurisdiction

Say I produce a tool that a user can enter a bunch of personal data into to accomplish some task. Say I distribute it as an EXE file or a web site or an app, but the tool does all its thinking and storage on hardware the user provides, and doesn't actually send me any user data.

Am I a "data processor" or "data controller" or a similar concept in any jurisdiction on the basis of my having determined how the tool works or, my having the ability to publish updates to it (automatic or otherwise) that might make it work differently?

I want to parse this as the user doing things with the user's own data, but a non-sophisticated user, who does not have the expertise to do things like access the data an app has stored on a phone without the app's cooperation, might see things differently.

Is the analysis any different between, say, a free spreadsheet program that behaves reasonably, versus a free spreadsheet program that automatically stops working forever if you enter too big a value in a field you have labeled "Monthly Income" (or otherwise exhibits user-hostile, locally-controlled use of stored state)?

Answer (score 4):

If this is more than just academic interest, your business plan should include hiring a lawyer.

But if the *data* never leaves the device of the user, and if you have no way to access that data unless *the user* installs an 'update' which totally changes your app, then you are neither processor not controller for that data. You can do absolutely nothing with the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definitions in Article 4 GDPR:

> (2) ‘processing’ means any operation or set of operations which is performed on personal data or on sets of personal data, whether or not by automated means, such as collection, recording, organisation, structuring, storage, adaptation or alteration, retrieval, consultation, use, disclosure by transmission, dissemination or otherwise making available, alignment or combination, restriction, erasure or destruction;

> (8) ‘processor’ means a natural or legal person, public authority, agency or other body which processes personal data on behalf of the controller;

> (7) ‘controller’ means the natural or legal person, public authority, agency or other body which, alone or jointly with others, determines the purposes and means of the processing of personal data; where the purposes and means of such processing are determined by Union or Member State law, the controller or the specific criteria for its nomination may be provided for by Union or Member State law;

If the application author has no access to the data then the author isn't a 'processor'.

If the application author does not determine the purpose and means of processing then the author isn't a 'controller'.

Comment: So then if I give you a computer program that you don't know what it does, and you feed in some personal data and run it, I as the program author might be a "controller" because I determined how and for what purpose the program operated on the data. Do I have that right?

Comment: In your scenario, how/why are you in the position of determining the purpose and means of processing?

Comment: As the author of the program, I determine how the program processes data. I could decide it should process it by means of sorting it and counting the most common first name, or by means of running it through an anomaly detector to identify people who are unusual relative to the others in the data set. This might also count as determining the purpose of the processing: I presumably had some purpose in mind when I wrote the code to accomplish it.

Comment: Why would I run your program, though? Are you my employer, for example?

Comment: You might not have a particular reason. Or maybe it is a program you find useful for one or more of the things it does, like a spreadsheet program or a program that can capitalize a whole list of names, among other features. Maybe it is a game and it collects your name and high score and saves it on your PC, and you want to play it.

Comment: If the author has no connection to the data, isn't aware of the existence of the data, I don't see how they can determine the purpose and means of processing the data. If I run an app that helps me organise and analyse customer data, the fact the author made a button that says "sort by name" doesn't mean the author determines the purpose and means of processing the data.